# UserSchema class object returns empty dict

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I have data in my sqlite db, but when I use UserSchema object I get an empty dict.

```
ma = Marshmallow()
# User Schema
class UserSchema(ma.Schema):

    class Meta:
        fields = (
            "id",
            "fname", 
            "mname", 
            "lname", 
            "dob", 
            "user_type", 
            "email", 
            "mobile_phone", 
            "landline_phone",
            "place_of_birth", 
            "government_id", 
            "government_id_number",
            "registered",
            "modified"
            )

# Init Schema 
user_schema = UserSchema()
```

but when I use it with `get` endpoint.

```
@api_blueprint.route("/api/users", methods=["GET"])
def get_users():
    all_users = User.query.all()
    result = user_schema.dump(all_users)
    return jsonify(result)
```

result is always coming out to be `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `many=True` to dump method if you want to serialize multiple objects.

`result = user_schema.dump(all_users, many=True)`